# Identify if list has consecutive elements that are equal

Tags: python, list

I'm trying to identify if a large list has consecutive elements that are the same.

So let's say:

```
lst = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 5, 6]
```

And in this case, I would return true, since there are two consecutive elements `lst[4]` and `lst[5]`, are the same value.

I know this could probably be done with some sort of combination of loops, but I was wondering if there were a more efficient way to do this?

Comment: Loop. Singular. And I doubt it. You'd have to look at every element once to know if there wasn't a consecutive pair.

Comment: Also see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5389507/iterating-over-every-two-elements-in-a-list and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33116880/how-do-i-check-if-two-consecutive-numbers-integers-in-a-list-have-the-same-val

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can use [`itertools.groupby()`](https://docs.python.org/dev/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) and a generator expression within `any()`
<sup>*</sup>:

```
>>> from itertools import groupby
>>> any(sum(1 for _ in g) > 1 for _, g in groupby(lst))
True
```

Or as a more Pythonic way you can use `zip()`, in order to check if at least there are two equal consecutive items in your list:

```
>>> any(i==j for i,j in zip(lst, lst[1:])) # In python-2.x,in order to avoid creating a 'list' of all pairs instead of an iterator use itertools.izip()
True
```

Note: The first approach is good when you want to check if there are more than 2 consecutive equal items, otherwise, in this case the second one takes the cake!

---

<sup>* Using `sum(1 for _ in g)` instead of `len(list(g))` is very optimized in terms of memory use (not reading the whole list in memory at once) but the latter is slightly faster.</sup>

Comment: Lose 1 for the first solution. Gain 1 for the second. The `itertools` one is no where near as clear.

Comment: @Holloway Yep, I just mentioned the advantage of first approach.

Answer (score 9):

You can use a **simple** [`any`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#any) condition:

```
lst = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 5, 6]
any(lst[i]==lst[i+1] for i in range(len(lst)-1))
#outputs:
True
```

`any` return `True` if any of the iterable elements are `True`

Comment: Could you please explain what `any` function does? Thanks

Comment: This would be my answer. Worth noting `xrange` is better if you're using python2.

Comment: @VaibhavBajaj, return `True` if any of the arguments (or things iterated over) is `True`

Answer (score 4):

If you're looking for an efficient way of doing this and the lists are numerical, you would probably want to use `numpy` and apply the `diff` (difference) function:

```
>>> numpy.diff([1,2,3,4,5,5,6])
array([1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1])
```

Then to get a single result regarding whether there are any consecutive elements:

```
>>> numpy.any(~numpy.diff([1,2,3,4,5,5,6]).astype(bool))
```

This first performs the `diff`, inverts the answer, and then checks if `any` of the resulting elements are non-zero.

Similarly,

```
>>> 0 in numpy.diff([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 5, 6])
```

also works well and is similar in speed to the `np.any` approach (credit for this last version to [heracho](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4759645/heracho)).

Comment: Wouldn't this return `True` if there were any duplicates? It sounds like the question was asking for consecutive duplicated values.

Comment: @johnchase: No, as the `diff` works on consecutive elements (without sorting)

Comment: Okay, I got it now. Nice solution!

Comment: (0 in np.diff([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 5, 6])) would do it too.

Comment: @heracho - good point - I had expected `np.any` to provide significant speed up in comparison with `in`, but it turns out that they are very similar in speed when testing with `%%timeit` in ipython!

Answer (score 2):

Here a more general `numpy` one-liner:

```py
number = 7
n_consecutive = 3
arr = np.array([3, 3, 6, 5, 8, 7, 7, 7, 4, 5])
#                              ^  ^  ^ 
 
np.any(np.convolve(arr == number, v=np.ones(n_consecutive), mode='valid') 
       == n_consecutive)[0]
```

This method always searches the whole array, while the approach from *@Kasramvd* ends when the condition is first met. So which method is faster dependents on how sparse those cases of consecutive numbers are.
If you are interested in the positions of the consecutive numbers, and have to look at all elements of the array this approach should be faster (for larger arrays (or/and longer sequences)).

```
idx = np.nonzero(np.convolve(arr==number, v=np.ones(n_consecutive), mode='valid') 
                             == n_consecutive)
# idx = i: all(arr[i:i+n_consecutive] == number)
```

If you are not interested in a specific value but at all consecutive numbers in general a slight variation of *@jmetz*'s answer:

```
np.any(np.convolve(np.abs(np.diff(arr)), v=np.ones(n_consecutive-1), mode='valid') == 0)
#                  ^^^^^^
# EDIT see djvg's comment
```

Comment: The `any(convolve(diff(...), ...), ...)` solution yields false positives: it basically calculates a moving sum of the differences between consecutive elements, then checks if this sum is zero anywhere. However, the sum of **nonzero** differences (i.e. consecutive elements NOT equal) can also be zero. Minimal example: `arr=[1,0,1,0,1]`, `n_consecutive=3`. The issue also becomes evident if you look at the equivalent convolution kernel for the example: `[1,0,-1]`

Comment: you are right. I guess one easy fix is to take the absolute values of the difference.

Answer (score 1):

Starting in `Python 3.10`, the new [`pairwise`](https://docs.python.org/3.10/library/itertools.html?highlight=pairwise#itertools.pairwise) function provides a way to slide through pairs of consecutive elements, so that we can test the quality between consecutive elements:

```
from itertools import pairwise

any(x == y for (x, y) in pairwise([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 5, 6]))
# True
```

---

The intermediate result of `pairwise`:

```
pairwise([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 5, 6])
# [(1, 2), (2, 3), (3, 4), (4, 5), (5, 5), (5, 6)]
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple `for` loop should do it:

```
def check(lst):
    last = lst[0]
    for num in lst[1:]:
        if num == last:
            return True
        last = num
    return False


lst = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 5, 6]
print (check(lst)) #Prints True
```

Here, in each loop, I check if the current element is equal to the previous element.

Answer (score 0):

The convolution approach suggested in [scleronomic's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60596259) is very promising, especially if you're looking for more than two consecutive elements.

However, the implementation presented in that answer might not be the most efficient, because it consists of two steps: `diff()` followed by `convolve()`.

#### Alternative implementation

If we consider that the `diff()` can also be calculated using convolution, we can combine the two steps into a single convolution.

The following alternative implementation only requires a single convolution of the full signal, which is advantageous if the signal has many elements.

Note that we cannot take the absolute values of the `diff` (to prevent false positives, as mentioned in [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38708692/identify-if-list-has-consecutive-elements-that-are-equal/60596259?noredirect=1#comment123125762_60596259)), so we add some random noise to the unit kernel instead.

```py
# example signal
signal = numpy.array([1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0])
# minimum number of consecutive elements
n_consecutive = 3
# convolution kernel for weighted moving sum (with small random component)
rng = numpy.random.default_rng()
random_kernel = 1 + 0.01 * rng.random(n_consecutive - 1)
# convolution kernel for first-order difference (similar to numpy.diff)
diff_kernel = [1, -1]
# combine the kernels so we only need to do one convolution with the signal
combined_kernel = numpy.convolve(diff_kernel, random_kernel, mode='full')
# convolve the signal to get the moving weighted sum of differences
moving_sum_of_diffs = numpy.convolve(signal, combined_kernel, mode='valid')
# check if moving sum is zero anywhere
result = numpy.any(moving_sum_of_diffs == 0)
```

See the [DSP guide](https://www.dspguide.com/ch6.htm) for a detailed discussion of convolution.

#### Timing

The difference between the two implementations boils down to this:

```py
def original(signal, unit_kernel):
    return numpy.convolve(numpy.abs(numpy.diff(signal)), unit_kernel, mode='valid')


def alternative(signal, combined_kernel):
    return numpy.convolve(signal, combined_kernel, mode='valid')
```

where `unit_kernel = numpy.ones(n_consecutive - 1)` and `combined_kernel` is defined above.

Comparison of these two functions, using `timeit`, shows that `alternative()` can be several times faster, for small kernel sizes (i.e. small value of `n_consecutive`). However, for large kernel sizes the advantage becomes negligible, because the convolution becomes dominant (compared to the `diff`).

Notes:

- For large kernel sizes I would prefer the original two-step approach, as I think it is easier to understand.
- Due to numerical issues it may be necessary to replace `numpy.any(moving_sum_of_diffs == 0)` by `numpy.any(numpy.abs(moving_sum_of_diffs) < very_small_number)`, see e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6598240).

Answer (score -1):

My solution for this if you want to find out whether 3 consecutive values are equal to 7. For example, a tuple of intList = (7, 7, 7, 8, 9, 1):

```
for i in range(len(intList) - 1):
        if intList[i] == 7 and intList[i + 2] == 7 and intList[i + 1] == 7:
            return True
    return False
```