# How to check if list has a specific consecutive equal elements?

Tags: python, list

I was looking at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38708743/9710966) answer, which shows how to identify if the list has any consecutive equal elements.

In a given list `lst = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 5, 6]`

`any(i==j for i,j in zip(lst, lst[1:]))` will return True since two 5s are equal neighbors. However, this piece of code checks for **any** consecutive equal elements.

How do I change this code to check for a specific element, say 5, in the given list?

Comment: use [stack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_(abstract_data_type)) data structure

Comment: `(i==5) and (i==j) ` or whatever other element you want to check for.

Comment: You can even shorten that to `i == j == 5`.

Comment: Or simply `(5, 5) in zip(lst, lst[1:])`, without any need for `any`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `any(i==j==5 for i,j in zip(lst, lst[1:]))` to check for 5's.